# Make webstorm default es6 for javascript

Tags: webstorm

How can I make webstorm set es6 as the javascript language default for any new projects imported via github?

I rarely have a project now that uses es5 and since I often import many new projects from github with no .idea settings this would save me some time.

Comment: @MikhailBatcer done

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To set the *default* language level for JavaScript, go to 
`File > *DEFAULT Settings* > Languages and Frameworks > JavaScript`.

[image: ES6 as default JS level]

Answer (score 3):

Go to [`File | Settings | Languages and Frameworks | JavaScript`](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/javascript.html) and here change option `JavaScript language version` to `ECMAScript 6`.

Also will be useful **[JetBrains screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbfkcmxLLKY)**.

Comment: But that changes the ECMAScript Version just for the current project. The question was rather changing it as default. @Nikos, could you change the default ECMAScript version?

Answer (score 0):

You can change global settings on the initial window when all projects are closed.

[image]
[image]
[image]